# %dir doesn't seem to work in spec file

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

It's my understanding of `%dir` that if I have

```
%files
%dir /foo/bar
```

That I now do not have to list each file individually of `/foo/bar`. However when I build my RPM in OBS I'm getting,

```
error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /foo/bar/baz
   /foo/bar/quz
```

What could cause this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [**Maximum RPM: Taking the RPM Package Manager to the Limit**](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html)

> **if a directory is specified in the `%files` list, the contents of that directory, and the contents of every directory under it, will automatically be included in the package.** While this feature can be handy (assuming you are sure that every file under the directory should be packaged) there are times when this could be a problem.
>
> The way to get around this, is to use the `%dir` directive. **By adding this directive to the line containing the directory, RPM will package only the directory itself, regardless of what files are in the directory at the time the package is created.**

You want to add the directory as if it were a file, **without `%dir`.**

Comment: Yep, found it out just a second too late. I updated the answer (I like that snippet better, if you're not ok I'll submit it separately).